# LaTeX markup and dollar signs in code

Tags: bug, status-completed, tex

Can someone explain to me, what happens in [this question on mine](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7017/187)? I wanted to write something like

`$KernelID` and `$ProcessID`

but in the question it seems like the LaTeX markup got confused:

---

[image]

---

Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: Very annoying. I had to cheat...

Comment: It has been like this for a while now, I think it's a bug in how MathJax and MarkDown are separated.  I added the bug tag, this is something worth looking at by SE staff.  See [here](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/983510#983510) and the subsequent comments too.

Comment: Thanks, I've been meaning to post about that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have checked in a fix for this; it will work as expected in the next build of the site.

The separation of Markdown and LaTeX wasn't taking code spans into account, so when seeing

```
`$foo` and `$bar`
```

it prevented Markdown rendering in the part between the two dollar signs. The Markdown renderer thus saw

```
`[something I'm not touching]bar`,
```

turning *the whole thing* into a code span, and eventually we ended up with

```
<code>$foo` and `$bar</code>
```

Comment: Thank you very much!