# Dollar signs and links

Tags: discussion, bug, markdown, tex

The following Markdown code is mis-typeset on the main site:

```
[`$MachineEpsilon`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$MachineEpsilon.html),
$\epsilon$ is $2^{-52}$.
```

The key conditions seem to be a `$` in the URL followed by two math modes in the same paragraph.  It doesn't seem to matter whether the math is inline or displayed, enclosed in `$` or `$$`, respectively.

Do others have this problem?

(I'm using Safari Version 10.0.3 (11602.4.8.0.1).)

Comment: It's a known problem with MathJax. Let me search the older post about it..

Comment: Well, I'm not sure this is *known*. I tagged it as a bug and I should probably report the other issue as well.

Comment: Related: http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/529/121

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue with the broken preview? The code is `Import["http://halirutan.github.io/Mathematica-SE-Tools/decode.m"]["http://i.stack.imgur.com/a9v8Y.png"]`. @Mr.Wizard Should I include my answer in the question?

Comment: @halirutan It seems to format properly in Safari: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTAyy.png

Comment: Another incarnation of this bug:  [A link with a dollar sign in the url](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/$InputFileName.html) followed by `A code block with an explicit dollar sign: $`.  Appeared in e.g. rev 4 of [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29137/11035).  (Kindly ignore my mucking up of the edit history while I tried to fix/track this bug...)

Answer (score 8):

Another workaround is to encode the "$" as "%24" in the URL:

```
[`MachineEpsilon`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/%24MachineEpsilon.html),
$\epsilon$ is $2^{-52}$.
```

Answer (score 6):

This seems to be a work-around.

[image follows]

---

[image: markdown]

---

[end image]

Answer (score 4):

For one we have this [old question of mine](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/473/187) which seemed fixed. Then, we have an issue with [dollar signs in code blocks](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/529/121) that can sometimes to solved by additionally indenting the block. Other than that, I have issues when my code-blocks contain dollar signs (this is only a sample code..):

[image: gr]

This is annoying too since I finally moved to use dollar-variables like WReach does. For answers, I now have to rewrite every code or fall back to my old habit of not using dollar signs at all :(